# AWS RDS-DB:Connect works for user but not for role

Tags: typescript, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I can assign the same policy to a user and a role in AWS IAM and when I try to connect to RDS using the role it does not work, but when I connect using the user, it does work. I've set the same policy on the role and the user and setup my code so I can toggle between using the user directly and the user assuming the role. The only difference is whether or not the cred variable has a credentials property in it.

Both the user and the assumed role are able to access the SecretsManager, but only the user can access the RDS database. The RDS logs show that PAM authentication failed for the role, so there's something going on.

```
  const cred = false ? {} : {
    credentials: await new STSClient({ region: "us-east-2" }).send(new AssumeRoleCommand({
      RoleArn: "... valid role arn ...",
      RoleSessionName: "Test",
    })).then(role => {
      if (!role.Credentials?.AccessKeyId || !role.Credentials.SecretAccessKey) throw "failed to assume role";
      console.log("Role Assumed");
      return {
        accessKeyId: role.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: role.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: role.Credentials.SessionToken,
      };
    })
  };
  const { SecretString: normalstr } = await new SecretsManagerClient({ region: "us-east-2", ...cred }).send(new GetSecretValueCommand({
    SecretId: "... valid secret arn ...",
    VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT",
  }));
  const env = JSON.parse(normalstr);
  const rds = new Signer({
    region: env.DB_REGION,
    hostname: env.DB_HOSTNAME,
    port: +env.DB_PORT,
    username: auth.user,
    ...cred
  });
  
  const db = await getPrismaClient(rds);

  db.customer.findUnique({...});
  // The role gets: User `user` was denied access on the database `db.public`
  // The user gets a successful query
```

1. I've looked everywhere for any deny statements and can't find any in the user, role, or policy. I can't find any kind of resource policy for the database in RDS. Neither the role nor the user have permissions boundary set.
2. All of the AssumeRole permissions are correctly set because the assumed role can access the secrets.
3. Running the same code with the same role in a lambda gives me the same error (which started this investigation).
4. I also had a problem with ec2 a while ago that I worked around by just putting the user access key directly in the secrets, which really isn't what AWS wants you to do, but the way it's supposed to work literally doesn't.
5. The user has no other permissions or policies attached, so it is definitely coming from this policy.

The important thing to remember is that I have the same policy on the user and the role, and both can access the secrets manager, which is one of the items in the policy, but only the user can access the db, which is the other item in the policy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being because I was trying to construct the connection string using a URL object. Somehow it broke for the role but not the user. I figured it out by logging the password (the signed RDS token) and then pasting it directly into PG Admin. It worked.

Long story short: Don't do this:

```
    const dburl = new URL("https://dud");
    dburl.username = username;
    dburl.password = password;
    dburl.hostname = DB_HOSTNAME;
    dburl.port = DB_PORT;
    dburl.pathname = DB_NAME;
    dburl.search = "?sslmode=require";
    // cut https: and set the protocol
    return "postgres:" + dburl.toString().slice(6);
```

Do this:

```
    return `postgres://${encodeURIComponent(username)}:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@${DB_HOSTNAME}:${DB_PORT}/${encodeURIComponent(DB_NAME)}?sslmode=require`
```